# django newb, not seeing postback

Tags: django

I'm vaguely doing the django tutorial.

```
<form action="." method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="language" value="{{ fbuser.language|escape }}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Change" />
</form>

def canvas(request):
    if request.POST != {}: assert False, request.POST
```

The assert never fires, and my `request.POST` is always `{}` and the page renders as if i refreshed it.   I'm pretty sure my canvas is getting called because if I change the form action attribute to "foobar" I get a django error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.0.106:8000/fbsample/canvas/foobar
```

EDIT: I have now tried having my postback URL go to 'foobar/'.  In the server log I see the post happen, but it redirects to canvas?  and foobar is never called?  I'm starting to suspect that the pyfacebook middleware is doing something funky, it would be helpful if you guys can confirm that this behavior is crazy...

Comment: what does your urls.py look like?

Answer (score 2):

`request.POST` evaluates to `False` if it's empty, but this is not the `dict` object, it might not support comparison operations to ordinary `dict` object. It would be better if you do:

```
if request.POST:
    assert False
```